# Which Data Lake Platform support three types of data?

Tags: delta-lake

If data lake is a repository with unstructured, semi-structured and structured data, is it physically implemented in a single DB technology? Which ones support the three types of data?

Answer (score 0):

That's a broad question, but [Delta Lake](https://delta.io/) supports all of these data types. Of course many things are dependent on the specific access patterns, but it's all doable with Delta.